# Would handling each TCP connection in a separate thread improve latency?

Tags: multithreading, qt, latency, qtcpsocket

I have an FTP server, implemented on top of QTcpServer and QTcpSocket.

I take advantage of the signals and slots mechanism to support multiple TCP connections simultaneously, even though I have a single thread. My code returns as soon as possible to the event loop, it doesn't block (no wait functions), and it doesn't use nested event loops anywhere. That way I already have **cooperative multitasking**, like Win3.1 applications had.

But a lot of other FTP servers are multithreaded. Now I'm wondering if using a **separate thread** for handling each TCP connection would improve performance, and especially **latency**.

On one hand, threads add to latency because you need to start a new thread for each new connection, but on the other, with my cooperative multitasking, other TCP connections have to wait until I've returned to the main loop before their `readyRead()`/`bytesWritten()` signals can be handled.

Comment: Improve "latency"? No.  Improve "responsiveness"?  Only if you're blocking on reads; and the socket I/O blocks your UI.  That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current system and ignoring file I/O time one processor is always doing something useful if there's something useful to be done, and waiting ready-to-go if there's nothing useful to be done.   If this were a single processor (single core) system you would have maximized throughput.  This is often a very good design -- particularly for an FTP server where you don't usually have a human waiting on a packet-by-packet basis.

You have also minimized **average** latency (for a single processor system.)   What you do not have is **consistent** latency.   Measuring your system's performance is likely to show a lot of ***jitter*** -- a lot of variation in the time it takes to handle a packet.   Again because this is FTP and not real-time process control or human interaction, jitter may not be a problem.

Now, however consider that there is probably more than one processor available on your system and that it may be possible to overlap I/O time and processing time.

To take full advantage of a multi-processor(core) system you need some concurrency.

This normally translates to using multiple threads, but it may be possible to achieve concurrency via asynchronous (non-blocking) file reads and writes.

However, adding multiple threads to a program opens up a huge can-of-worms.

If you do decide to go the MT route, I'd suggest that you consider depending on a thread-aware I/O library.   QT may provide that for you (I'm not sure.)  If not, take a look at boost::asio (or ACE for an older, but still solid solution).  You'll discover that using the MT capabilities of such a library involves a considerable investment in learning time; however as it turns out the time to add on multithreading "by-hand" and get it right is even worse.

So I'd say stay with your existing solution unless you are worried about unused Processor cycles and/or jitter in which case start learning QT's multithreading support or boost::asio.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to start a new thread for each new connection? Could you not just have a pool of threads that acts on requests as and when they arrive. This should reduce some of the latency. I have to say that in general a multi-threaded FTP server should be more responsive that a single-threaded one. Is it possible to have an event based FTP server?